# Multiclass classification in imbalanced dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, classification, multiclass-classification

I have this dataset whose labels counts are as following:
[image]

I do understand that it's very imbalanced. I tried over sampling and under sampling and they gave good accuracy for training. however of course they gave validation accuracy very low. I also tried class weights as follows:
`class_weights = class_weight.compute_class_weight('balanced',                                                np.unique(Y),                                              Y)`
and this also gave low accuracy for validation. I even excluded exluded the other labels and left only the 5 highest labels still get about 36% validation accuracy and  92% training accuracy. I think that all of this because of over fitting. But my model is very simple; it's:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(MAX_NB_WORDS,int(len(word_index)*.25),input_length=X.shape[1]),
    tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(64,dropout=.5)),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(64, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(5, activation='sigmoid')
])
```

I am confused and don't know what to do?

Comment: I noticed that you are using sigmoid activation in the output layer. What type of task are you training the model? ReLU is often used with Softmax.